# Trying to get the smallest number from an array always return "0"

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, select, dice

I am writing a dice roller program with VB 2010 express that rolls many different types of dice and up to 15 of each type. I currently have 4 options on for the program. Choose how many dice, Choose how many sides on dice, Choose only the highest roll and choose only the lowest roll. Everything seems to be working as intended with the exception of the "Use lowest Die" code. If anyone can please point me into the right direction or give me an example of how to do it better. Thanks in advance for any help

```
    Dim DiceArray(frmRoller.cmbNumberofdice.Text) As Long
    Dim iTemp As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim numofDice As Integer
    Dim CountArrayHigh(100) As Integer
    Dim CountArrayLow(100) As Integer
    numofDice = frmRoller.cmbNumberofdice.Text

    Select Case frmRoller.cmbChooseDie.Text
        Case "D4"
            For i = 1 To numofDice
                iTemp = D4()
                DiceArray(i) = iTemp
                If iTemp > CountArrayHigh(0) Then CountArrayHigh(0) = iTemp
                If iTemp < CountArrayLow(0) Then CountArrayLow(0) = iTemp

            Next i

            highDie = CountArrayHigh(0)
            lowDie = CountArrayLow(0)
```

Comment: Post the rest of the code please

Comment: That code fragment is kinda useless.  Show us the code that is producing unexpected results as well as an explanation of the desired results and where the anomaly might be happening.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and add `Option Strict On` at the top of your code or set it in the project's properties.  This line:  `Dim DiceArray(frmRoller.cmbNumberofdice.Text) As Long` is wrong.  You are trying to allocate an array using a string.  Without `Option Strict On`, VB will attempt to convert that to a number which will fail if anything other than a valid integer is in the text box.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, arrays are zero based. So declaring an array like `Dim DiceArray(frmRoller.cmbNumberofdice.Text) As Long`, apart from not screening the user's input, is actually creating the array one element larger than needed. We need more code to be certain, but I'd say you're forgetting the zero element. Also Long seems like overkill... it can hold -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.